# JSGrid header with tooltips

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsgrid

After searching for a long time on how to create a proper tooltip for JsGrid, I have created the following version:

```
headerTemplate: function() { 
    return $("<div>").text(this.title)
         .append('<div class="tooltip"><img height="20" width="20" id="tooltip" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-help-outline-128.png" /><span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span></div>');
```

However the main problem with this tooltip at the moment is that when you have a very long tooltip, it will get cut off by the JsGrid Header due to its `overflow-x: hidden` and `overflow-y:scroll`.

For this reason I had put the position of the tooltip on `position:absolute`, however this results in when the grid will not completely fit on the screen that the tooltips are on wrong positions.

I have found that when you have a `<div>` with `position:relative` around the element with `overflow` on it, that you can overrule it then with a `position: absolute` div inside it. However since the grid gets generated from Javascript completely I was wondering if there is another way to do this or if I have to modify the JsGrid generation.

The full example can be found on:
https://jsfiddle.net/SlowFing/1hx84hv7/

Answer (score 1):

**This works for me :**

```
headerTemplate: function () {
    var TdObj = $('<th class="text-center"></th>')
    return TdObj.prop("title","boo" ).text("column title");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the header cell `position:relative` and then absolute the tooltip. Try these changes..https://jsfiddle.net/1hx84hv7/12/

**CSS**

```
.jsgrid-header-cell {
    position:relative;
}

.tooltip {
   position: absolute;
   display: inline-block;
   border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   top: 10%;
   right: 100%;
   margin-top: -5px;
   border-width: 5px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color: transparent black transparent transparent;
}
```

Comment: This is not working either, it will just result in the same cut off tooltip, the reason it seems working for you is because you wrote `.jsgird` instead of `.jsgrid`

Tried this approach myself also, but it was not working either.